# Contador em um valor de um dicionário

Tags: python, dicionário

Sou iniciante em programação e estou fazendo um exercício no qual eu preciso contar os votos de determinados números de acordo com o número da camisa do jogador. Por exemplo, se eu digitar no programa 23, 3 vezes, o número 23 terá 3 votos. Gostaria de saber se há algum modo de ir acrescentando o número de votos no valor da chave.

```
while numero_camisa != 0:
numero_camisa = int(input('Informe o número da camisa do jogador ou zero para sair: '))
if numero_camisa < 0 or numero_camisa > 23:
    print('Número da camisa inválido, favor informar um número entre 1 e 23.')
votos_atletas[numero_camisa] = #acrescentar o número de votos conforme o número da camisa.
```

Meu código até aqui, ficou assim. Agora fica a dúvida, existe um modo de acrescentar o número de votos de acordo com o que o usuário for informando ?

Comment: Esse exercício se encontra no site https://wiki.python.org.br/ExerciciosListas, exercício nº 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Python possui, além da estrutura de dicionários que pode ser utilizada, uma estrutura nativa na biblioteca `collections` para a solução deste problema: `Counter`. Basta você armazenar todos os votos em uma lista:

```
from collections import Counter

votos = []

while True:
    numero_camisa = int(input('Número da camisa: '))
    if numero_camisa == 0:
        break
    elif 0 < numero_camisa < 23:
        votos.append(numero_camisa)
    else:
        print('Número inválido')


votacao = Counter(votos)

print(votacao)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/KnowledgeableHandsomeGeeklog)</sup>

Se a entrada fosse, por exemplo, `[1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4]`, a saída seria:

```
Counter({2: 3, 1: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})
```

Comment: Não sabia dessa, vai me ajudar bastante nos estudos, obrigado por compartilhar.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa acessar o valor atual do dicionário para o valor de `numero_camisa`e aumentar esse valor em 1.

Antes de ver a resposta, tente fazer você mesmo desta forma. Como você abre o valor atual de votos do jogador `numero_camisa`? Como você faz para atribuir valor a uma variável?

---

```
votos_atletas[numero_camisa] = votos_atletas[numero_camisa] + 1
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, tinha me esquecido, tentei atribuir o valor de todas as formas, mas esqueci de atribuir a chave do valor, muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada. Aceita a resposta se funcionou.