# Erro ao calcular um valor em loop

Tags: python, loop

```
#O usuário informa o número de alunos totais na sala, em seguida são declaradas as variáveis que complementarão os loops
alunos = int(input("Qual o número de alunos na sala?\n"))
notasAlunos = []
count = 0
#loop de armazenamento de notasXalunos
while count < alunos:
    notaAluno = int(input("Qual a nota do aluno " + str(count + 1) + "? (0 a 100 pontos)\n"))
    notasAlunos.append(notaAluno)
    count = count + 1
#count zerado para ser reutilizado no próximo loop
count = 0
#Variáveis de notas
menorNota = 100
maiorNota = 0
alunosMeN,alunosMaN = 0,0
#loop de verificação do valor de notas (min e max), e verificação de notas mínimas ou máximas iguais
while count < len(notasAlunos):
    if notasAlunos[count] < menorNota:
        menorNota = notasAlunos[count]
    if notasAlunos[count] > maiorNota:
        maiorNota = notasAlunos[count]
    if notasAlunos[count] == menorNota:
        alunosMeN = alunosMeN + 1
    elif notasAlunos[count] == maiorNota:
        alunosMaN = alunosMaN + 1
    count = count + 1
#print com os valores da maior e menor nota, junto ao número de alunos que tiraram determinada nota
print("A maior nota tirada foi ", maiorNota, " Essa nota foi tirada por ", alunosMaN, " aluno(s)\n")
print("A menor nota tirada foi ", menorNota, " Essa nota foi tirada por ", alunosMeN, " aluno(s)\n")
```

Dado o código acima, ao inserir, por exemplo, `5` alunos, com as notas `10, 22, 10, 100, 100` O programa não exibe 2 alunos com as maiores notas como o desejado, mas sim, 3 alunos.
Por que isso ocorre? Como posso solucionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Problema está sendo no segundo `while`, a maior nota muda de acordo com que ele passa no `loop` e o contador de alunos com a menor e maior nota continua somando, eu mudaria a forma de pegar a maior e menor nota para o código abaixo:

```
menorNota = min(notasAlunos)
maiorNota = max(notasAlunos)
```

o código todo ficaria assim:

```
#O usuário informa o número de alunos totais na sala, em seguida são declaradas as variáveis que complementarão os loops
alunos = int(input("Qual o número de alunos na sala?\n"))
notasAlunos = []
count = 0
#loop de armazenamento de notasXalunos
while count < alunos:
    notaAluno = int(input("Qual a nota do aluno " + str(count + 1) + "? (0 a 100 pontos)\n"))
    notasAlunos.append(notaAluno)
    count = count + 1
#count zerado para ser reutilizado no próximo loop
count = 0
#Variáveis de notas
menorNota = min(notasAlunos)
maiorNota = max(notasAlunos)
alunosMeN,alunosMaN = 0,0
#loop de verificação do valor de notas (min e max), e verificação de notas mínimas ou máximas iguais
while count < len(notasAlunos):    
    if notasAlunos[count] == menorNota:
        alunosMeN = alunosMeN + 1
    if notasAlunos[count] == maiorNota:
        alunosMaN = alunosMaN + 1
    count = count + 1
#print com os valores da maior e menor nota, junto ao número de alunos que tiraram determinada nota
print("A maior nota tirada foi ", maiorNota, " Essa nota foi tirada por ", alunosMaN, " aluno(s)\n")
print("A menor nota tirada foi ", menorNota, " Essa nota foi tirada por ", alunosMeN, " aluno(s)\n")
```

Comment: Um pequeno reparo: a nivel de performance a condição do `while`, visto o valor de `len(notasAlunos)` ser constante nesse ponto, escusas de executar sempre `len(...)` a cada loop, https://ideone.com/0BNU7s, ao usar `while` podes/deves atribuir esse valor a uma variável previamente, ou mudas o ciclo para um `for ...`

Answer (score 4):

Ocorre porque você misturou as lógicas num mesmo trecho de código.

```
while count < len(notasAlunos):
    if notasAlunos[count] < menorNota:
        menorNota = notasAlunos[count]
    if notasAlunos[count] > maiorNota:
        maiorNota = notasAlunos[count]
    if notasAlunos[count] == menorNota:
        alunosMeN = alunosMeN + 1
    elif notasAlunos[count] == maiorNota:
        alunosMaN = alunosMaN + 1
    count = count + 1
```

Com esse laço você tanto define quais são as menor e maior notas e conta quantos alunos as possuem. Isso fere o princípio de unicidade do código.

[O que são "unidades de código"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216315/5878)

Para entender melhor, basta fazer um teste de mesa.

[O que é um Teste de Mesa? Como aplicá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878)

Além que seu código possui muitos vícios de linguagem, longe de ser considerado *pythonico*.

[O que é código pythônico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878)

Uma solução melhor seria semelhante a que apresentei [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/286777/5878), utilizando a classe `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter

numero_alunos = int(input("Qual o número de alunos na sala?\n"))
notas_alunos = [
    float(input("Nota do aluno {}? (0 a 100 pontos)".format(i+1))) 
        for i in range(numero_alunos)
]

maior_nota = max(notas_alunos)
menor_nota = min(notas_alunos)

classificacao = Counter(notas_alunos)

print("A maior nota tirada foi ", maior_nota, " Essa nota foi tirada por ", classificacao[maior_nota], " aluno(s)")
print("A menor nota tirada foi ", menor_nota, " Essa nota foi tirada por ", classificacao[menor_nota], " aluno(s)")
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/GrouchyCriticalOperation)</sup>

Comment: estou começando agora no python, e sim, eu defino as maiores e menores notas, porque é justamente o que tenho que fazer, para que possa fazer as comparações. Vou dar uma olhada nas referências, obrigado :D

Comment: @MuriloGambôa o problema é justamente fazer isso no mesmo laço. Por exemplo, a primeira nota é 10, que é maior que 0 (inicial), então você atualiza o valor para 10 e logo depois adiciona ao contador caso a nota do aluno é igual à maior nota. A maior nota não será 10, mas mesmo assim nesse laço você compara e adiciona o contador.

Comment: estava adicionando a nota, mas vi que não devo, e eu zero o contador, a adição no count ocorre ao fim de todas as verificações, e sem essa adição, o loop seria infinito

Comment: @MuriloGambôa Esse contador: `alunosMaN = alunosMaN + 1`

Answer (score 1):

No caso, basta zerar o count caso o valor da maior, ou menor nota seja atualizado, fazendo com que a contagem dos alunos com o mesmo valor (sendo o maior, ou o menor apenas) recomece.

```
    if notasAlunos[count] < menorNota:
        alunosMeN = 0
        menorNota = notasAlunos[count]
    if notasAlunos[count] > maiorNota:
        alunosMaN = 0
        maiorNota = notasAlunos[count]
```